# Android logcat shows app "interaction:" "BLOCKED"

Tags: android, logcat, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 to watch debug messages for my app in the logcat. The app is a blank project made with Delphi 11.

Setting the logcat filter to com.bookup has these two lines appear:

```
2022-01-16 16:07:41.227 1247-1378/? I/AppsFilter: interaction: PackageSetting{138dd45 com.bookup.ThisIsMikesTestProjectOfDoom/10332} -> PackageSetting{3e91e66 com.paypal.android.p2pmobile/10229} BLOCKED
0222-01-16 16:08:02.394 1247-1378/? I/AppsFilter: interaction: PackageSetting{138dd45 com.bookup.ThisIsMikesTestProjectOfDoom/10332} -> PackageSetting{3e91e66 com.paypal.android.p2pmobile/10229} BLOCKED
```

The PayPal app is running on the Android device.

Am I correct in understanding these lines to say that my empty app tried to "interact" with the PayPal app and was "blocked?" Is that normal?

Answer (score 12):

Your package doesn't seem to have the required visibility of PayPal package. You may need to add visibility for the required package in your app's Manifest.

Checkout for more info: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Edit: My original answer did not give much context or examples, hence adding a few things which may help

Apps targeting API level 30 and above (Android 11+) need to specify which other packages they need to see (or use) on the device. For this, developers need to add a `<queries>` tag in their apps' `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<manifest package="com.bookup.ThisIsMikesTestProjectOfDoom">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.paypal.android.p2pmobile" />
    <package android:name="com.example.other.package" />
  </queries>
  …
</manifest>
```

The `<package>` tag is one of the valid tags under `<queries>`. Other options can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element). Without the `<queries>` tag, [`AppsFilter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/AppsFilter.java) will not allow access of any package to your app, which is what you're seeing in your logcat.

You can read more on the new changes in Package visibility here:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/testing

Comment: You may want to consider improving this answer with an example, perhaps one taken from the linked article (don't forget to attribute any borrowed code)

Comment: People might miss the part that says, "The app is a blank project made with Delphi 11."

There is no way a blank project (Hello World) would have anything to do with PayPal. It is still a mystery to me why a blank project would trigger any logcat lines that mention any app other than itself.

Comment: Oh true, I totally missed that part

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `startForegroundService()`? Maybe the background service restriction blocked it.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background